# What kind of circuit is it (negative voltage generating)?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, negative

What is the name/type of this negative voltage-generating circuit?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Polarity-inverting buck-boost](http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1273276) is what it is called.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Buck-Boost converter.